# Weird data being returned

Tags: sequelize.js

I was hoping to get some advice on how to fix my data (if it's not normal). When I make a fetchAll call for the user model, the type of data I'm getting is

```
[
  user {
    dataValues: {
      id: 4,
      email: 'emais44@email.com',
      createdAt: '2020-08-05',
      updatedAt: '2020-08-05'
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 4,
      email: 'emais44@email.com',
      createdAt: '2020-08-05',
      updatedAt: '2020-08-05'
    },
    _changed: Set {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  user {
    dataValues: {
      id: 5,
      email: 'SDSU@test.com',
      createdAt: '2020-08-07',
      updatedAt: '2020-08-07'
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 5,
      email: 'SDSU@test.com',
      createdAt: '2020-08-07',
      updatedAt: '2020-08-07'
    },
    _changed: Set {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  user {
```

Is this normal? I was expecting something along the line of `[{user.data}, {user.data}]`. Any and all advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the raw option to true, like:

```
User.findAll({raw:true})
```

for more details: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-usage/#raw-queries

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Since your response I've been diving into the entire documentation in order to make sure I understand it all. Again thank you.